# Call another contract 's function in contract 's constructor failed

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I wrote two contract, the first Contract1 have a simple function, and the second Contract2 's constructor receive a Contract1 address and call the simple function.

I create Contract1 address, then use this address to create Contract2.

I found I can create Contract2 's address right in remix javascript vm, but fail in private net.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Contract1{
    function simple() external view returns (bool) {
        return true;
    }
}

contract Contract2{
    bool public result;
    constructor(address contract1Address) public {
        Contract1 contract1 = Contract1(contract1Address);
        result = contract1.simple();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have most of the answer.

You `pragma solidity ^0.4.18;` is untrue. You are using the `constructor` format that was introduced with `0.4.22`, so it does not compile with `0.4.18` as it claims it does.

As luck would have it, the issue seems to be related to the constructor. It's very new. Someone else reported that it creates a function signature that exactly matches the fallback function and that caused an unrelated issue. I suspect something similar is happening here.

What I found is that the contract compiles and works just fine when it's adjusted to the style of and compiled with an earlier compiler. I set it to `0.4.19` to match up with recent Truffle and I removed `^` to eliminate possible inconsistency since we can see the exact compiler is sure to be a problem.

Note that `0.4.19` does not understand `constructor` and that could be an issue with your deployment process.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.19;

contract Contract1{
    function simple() external view returns (bool) {
        return true;
    }
}

contract Contract2{
    bool public result;

    function Contract2(address contract1Address) public {
        Contract1 contract1 = Contract1(contract1Address);
        result = contract1.simple();
    }
}
```

Works as expected.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried it works fine as expected